# How can I get the list of Azure Regions in C#?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk

The Azure SDK for Java has [an enum](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/resources/fluentcore/arm/Region.html) with all of the Azure locations, public and national.

Is there similar functionality available for C#? It would be cleaner than using strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there similar functionality available for C#?

Yes, please refer to [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent), we could get [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/Region.cs) from github. More details please refer to screenshot.

demo code:

```
string region = Region.AsiaEast.ToString();
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you need them as List you can try:

```
typeof(AzureLocation).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```